# Specifying JVM arguments when calling a jar file?

Tags: java, jvm, arguments

I want to specify some JVM arguments when calling a jar file like so:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

I assumed I did it like so:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true jar filename.jar
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Do it like:

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar filename.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work, so perhaps I have another issue.

Comment: @Dominic Bou-Samra How are you testing that?

Comment: @Dominic Bou-Samra You can try to use JConsole to test the memory sizes of the Heap.

Comment: If you are not familiar with JCOncole, here is a good [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) about it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Got it sorted. Thanks for the JConsole tip. Worked well

Comment: Make sure the `-jar filaname.jar` is at the end. Doesn't work if `-Dmyarg=true` is after `-jar`

Answer (score 11):

```
java [Options] -jar  [jarfile] [Command Line Arguments]
```

Please refer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 4):

Don't put a space between the -D and java.awt.headless=true.

It should be -Djava.awt.headless=true.

Answer (score 4):

hype jar was missing , try

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar
```