# How To add some arguments into JVM?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, synthetica

I want to use look and feel jar files for java and the library is said i have to add some arguments into jvm

[You Can Read Here](http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1509385738000)

here is the arguments

```java
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=synthetica.base
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.table=synthetica.base
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing.plaf.synth=synthetica.base
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth=synthetica.base
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=synthetica.base
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=synthetica.base
--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.tree=synthetica.base
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=synthetica.base
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=synthetica.base
--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.awt=synthetica.base
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.action=synthetica.base
```

now i don't know from where and how i have to pass these arguments what should i do?

> **Edit:**
>   my question is not duplicate like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891123/specifying-jvm-arguments-when-calling-a-jar-file) i Just Don't know where jvm arguments file located

Comment: And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555030/swing-issue-on-java-10

Comment: @George Z no my Question is not duplicate i don't know where i have to put this values this is my main problem how ever i found solution.the answers in other questions just mentioned the arguments i was need to know where i have to add these arguments where is the JVM arguments file?sorry for my bad english