# How to specify these VM Arguments?

Tags: java, jvm

How do I specify `-Xms1g`, `-Xmx1k`, and `-XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to the Java VM when I run my application.

Comment: How do you run your application? And those arguments make no sense. A minimum of 1 gig, and a maximum of 1 kb? One sixty fourth the ram in a commodore 64?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying JVM arguments when calling a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891123/specifying-jvm-arguments-when-calling-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing your application?

1. Are you trying to get the heap dump if the application runs into Out Of Memory error, if yes, you can use `jconsole` and the right command is **`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`**
2. The flag **-Xmx** specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java virtual machine (JVM), while **-Xms** specifies the initial memory allocation pool and hence the value for **Xmx** should be greater than **Xms**,

   you would need to correct your argument values.